# InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html) states:

> The From: address can be the email
>   address of a registered administrator
>   (developer) of the application, the
>   **current user** if signed in with Google
>   Accounts...

This works fine for my app when the current user's Google Account happens to be a Gmail account. It used to work fine for non-Gmail google accounts also but of late I see an error:InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender
for non-Gmail google accounts. Am I missing any recent changes to the implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since May 10 (with the 1.5.0 SDK release) the additional restrictions where added:

> We have added two restrictions to the Mail API to improve the reliability of the service for all application.
>   Emails must be sent from email accounts managed by Google (either Gmail or a domain signed up for Google Apps).

It seems the documentation does not reflect this change yet.